# minimizing maximum of sum of functions

Tags: optimization

I am trying to perform the following optimization using KKT conditions.

min max(f1(x)+g1(x), f2(x)+g2(x))

I believe I need to follow the approach suggested here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331661/minimizing-sum-of-maximum-of-functions?rq=1

But I am getting thrown off by the maximum between the two functions  (f1+g1, f2+g2).

Comment: How can it be equivalent?? In the first case the answer is a sum of 2 values while in the second case the answer is one value.

Comment: I apologize for the badly written question. I did a few searches and edited the question.